# Different Body background image use html css

Tags: html, css, image, background

i use body background image different page different background image

Example

```
<body class="home">

<body class="contact">
```

but w3 validator error:
"Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open." , "Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored."

i can use with Jquery

```
<script>

    $('body').addClass("home");

</script>

<script>

    $('body').addClass("contact");

</script>
```

But i want use Html Css no Jquery please help me

Comment: so you want two different background images overlayed? or want them after the client does something?

Comment: yes. Example. home.html different bg image , contact.html different bgimage

Comment: First off, you really should only have one `body` in your document. You should use `div`s with those classes instead.

Comment: if its two different pages then you should give the body a class on EACH page.

Comment: yes work different class but w3 validator no syntax

Comment: body in header html static. page ise dinamic

Answer (score 0):

All right, you open one element `body` and then want to open another. One html  page must contain one `body` element. It's a standart.

Comment: In each different page you can create container for  you content, for example  `<body><div class="content">Content of your page </div></body>` and then add css properties to each container `div` such: `.content:{background-image:url ()}`

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting a different background image for EACH page home.html, and contact.html.

home should look like this.

```
<body class="home">
```

contact

```
<body class="contact">
```

then put the appropriate css with each for different backgrounds

Comment: page dinamic but body in header.html static

Comment: well if the page is dynamic then you will have to use jquery or javascript. How are you making it dynamic? are you using a specific framework?